# How to add perticular css class based on the button click?

Tags: css, typescript, ionic4

I'm designing Ionic 4 plus angular app, I create 3 buttons with 3 different colour to each other (suppose all buttons is in the first page), in the second page I'm using HTML fieldset. Now I want when I click on the first button then second-page fieldset border colour should be blue,
when I click on second button fieldset border colour should be red etc.
Below image shows what exactly I want.

[image: This is first page]

[image: This is second page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add class and remove class.Create a function that will remove class which border color is black and add class which border color is red and e.t.

```
    function myFunction() {
     var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
     element.classList.add("mystyle");//add class
    } 

    function myFunction() {
     var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
     element.classList.remove("mystyle");//remove class
    }
```

For better understanding read this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp
And this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp

Good Luck :)

Comment: hes after a click on the first page and class on the second page.

Comment: Direct access to the DOM is not recommended in Angular apps. If you want to add or remove a class from the template, using [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) would be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following code sample in your code. It is not a complete working example but this has the basic idea about that.

**page1.html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="gotoPage2('blue')" color="blue">First button</button>
<button ion-button (click)="gotoPage2('red')" color="red">Second button</button>
<button ion-button (click)="gotoPage2('green')" color="green">Third button</button>
```

**page1.ts**

```
public gotoPage2(event ,color ){
this.navCtrl.push(page2,{
color:color
});
}
```

**page2.ts**

```
export class Page2 {
value:any;
constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.color = navParams.get('color');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EmiCalPage');

  }

}
```

**page2.html**

```
<div [ngClass]="color" >

</div>
```